# Re-using code for lvalues and rvalues

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Suppose I have a copy constructor. This constructor calls a hierarchy of functions, passing the copied object as an lvalue reference.

Now, I also have a move constructor which basically could use the same function hierarchy as the copy constructor. This would work, since I can pass the rvalue argument to the lvalue hierarchy.

BUT somewhere down in the hierarchy, I have a function which would copy a resource in the lvalue case and 'steal' the resource in the rvalue case.

Is there a way to decide, whether the lvalue reference passed to that function originates from an rvalue? I guess not. Or what is the common approach, when you have a hierarchy of functions for copying which you could use for copy and move constructions and which only differ in very few functions?

Code sample:

```
class A{
    A(const A& a){
        initFrom(a);  
    }

    A(A&& a){
        initFrom(a); 
    }

    void initFrom(const A& a){
       // call a hierarchy of functions, of which one of them calls initResource(const A&)
    }

    void initResource(const A& a){

       if(a == rvalue reference){ // **** Here's the question... ****
           // steal resource
           this->ptr = a.ptr;
           a.ptr = nullptr;
       }
       else{
           // copy resource
           this->ptr = allocate...
           copy from a.ptr to this->ptr
       }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example to show us?

Comment: I get an inkling that `enable_if` and `is_rvalue_reference` is going to help, but a code sample (MCVE) gives it more context.

Comment: When someone asks you to improve a question, please don't just tack some stuff onto the end of the question and say "added X on request". Rather, *rework* your question to be better as a whole.

Comment: For your code as presented - no - there's no way.  Still, have you tried making the `init...` function hierarchy templated to accept `a` in either guise, then using [is_rvalue_refrence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_rvalue_reference) for your test? Or, pass an extra function argument down, or add a member data flag (bit wasteful as of no ongoing use, but that may or may not concern you and there'd be less repetitive argument passing if the hierarchy is deep).

Comment: As said in the answer by @KerrekSB, there IS actually a way to do it - "perfect forwarding". Please let me know, if (and how) this would not work in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example for perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename T>
A(T && t) { initFrom(std::forward<T>(a)); }

template <typename T>
void initFrom(T && t)
{
    // other calls
    initResource(std::forward<T>(t));
}

void initResource(A const & rhs) { /* copy from rhs */ }
void initResource(A && rhs)      { /* move from rhs */ }
```

(It seems that you should either be able to merge `initFrom` into the constructor, or otherwise your class may be trying to do too much and you should refactor it into single-responsibility components.)

Comment: Ok, I would say "perfect forwarding" is the perfect answer for this question, thanks! (However, I will consider the hint about the refactoring into simpler components.)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative here is to modify the `initFrom` to accept a "universal reference" to allow reference collapsing and then use `std::forward` for perfect forwarding. You may then need to re-factor the remaining call hierarchy.

```
class A{
    A(const A& a){
        initFrom(a);
    }

    A(A&& a){
        initFrom(a);
    }

    template <typename B>
    void initFrom(B&& a){ // reference collapsing applies
      // call a hierarchy of functions, of which one of them calls initResource(const A&)
      initResource(std::forward<B>(a));
    }

    void initResource(A&& a){
      // steal resource
      this->ptr = a.ptr;
      a.ptr = nullptr;
    }

    void initResource(const A& a){
      // copy resource
      this->ptr = allocate...
      //copy from a.ptr to this->ptr
    }
};
```

I think a simpler alternative is to first "move" the resource into you class before the `initFrom` is call.

```
    A(A&& a){
        this->ptr = a.ptr;
        a.ptr = nullptr;
        initFrom(a);
    }
```

But you mileage here may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your call hierarchy and what all those functions have to do except for passing down the object you might use another technique if you aim to store the object inside your class anyway.

```
class A {
    A(const A& a) {
        initFrom(A(a)); // take a copy here
    }
    A(A&& a) {
        initFrom(std::move(a)); // move here
    }

    void initFrom(A&& a) { 
        initResource(std::move(a)); // just pass down
    }

    void initResource(A&& a) {
        // you already have your copy of a here that you can store completely
        // or take its guts
    }
```

This way you only have to implement all the methods once (for an rvalue reference) and whether moving or taking a copy is handled directly inside the method call. 
Take care that you always have to std::move() to pass down the rvalue reference.